# Alarm clock or timing notification in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello i'm some new with flutter and i need to do an alarm or a timing notification.I need some like AlarmManager in Android Studio.

I'm taking the hour from my server so i need the alarm or notification runs with that hour. I'll be so grateful if someone can help me thanks.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager

Comment: Yeah something like that i'll test it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`flutter_local_notifications`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/) for configuring a timer and notification in Flutter.

Here's a code snippet that sends out an hourly notification.

```dart
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

// hourly notification schedule config, set to either `hours: 1` or `minutes: 60`
var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
    DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 60));

Future<void> _showNotificationHourly() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your other channel id',
      'your other channel name',
      'your other channel description',),
    );
    const IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        IOSNotificationDetails();
    const MacOSNotificationDetails macOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        MacOSNotificationDetails();
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        macOS: macOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    
    // https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/#scheduling-a-notification
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        'scheduled title',
        'scheduled body',
        scheduledNotificationDateTime,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
}
```